Offline conversions without GCLID or Google tags on website?
Say for instance I'm a company who values privacy and I want to manage my own on-site tracking. This tracking data will be fed to a backend, which can then upload conversions to Google Ads in batches. The idea here is that I can't have any 3P (Google) software running whatsoever on the frontend. As well, I may want to scrub any data from conversion stream before sending it to Google.
If I don't want to lean on GCLID, is there another way to do this? For example:
https://www.nsa.gov?campaign_id=12345
[campaign_id=12345] -> product_click
[campaign_id=12345] -> product_cart_add
[campaign_id=12345] -> product_buy(499.99)

[product_click, product_cart_add, product_buy(499.99)] -> ConversionTracker
// periodically batch results to Google
ConversionTracker.batch(google)

Or, should I find a way to use the GCLID?
